# React animation based on a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my problem: when a user clicks on a submit button, I want to slide in a banner from the top of the page if the submit wasn't successful (i.e. due to network problem).

After the banner has being displayed for 2 seconds, I want it to retract and go out of the view.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
export default class Base extends React.Component {
    ...

    renderErrMsg = () => {
        if(this.props.errMsg){
            return (
                <div className="errMsg">
                    {this.props.errMsg}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderErrMsg()}
                ...
            <div>
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to wrap `#errMsg` with `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` but it gives me an error:

> warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Base`.warning
>
> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Base`.

---

UPDATE: @Ted definitely pointed me to the right solution. In his solution, a state has been created to mirror the value stored in a props. I realised that there is no need to create the state variable by using `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentWillUpdate`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.application.errorMessage){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.dispatch(removeErrMsg())
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

I did have to write the `removeErrMsg` action so that `dispatch` can clear the error message in the store once it is shown.

The mistakes that I made:

1. my import statment was wrong: I had `import { ReactCSSTransitionGroup } from 'react/addons'`, but it should be `import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'`
2. When rendering the error message, the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` portion should be inside the `render()` method instead of the `renderErrMsg` method. `renderErrMsg` returns the content to be animated but it shouldn't return the `TransitionGroup` along with it. Otherwise, there won't be any animation. Because when there is no error message, the entire `errMsg` div along with `TransitionGroup` becomes null and the error message div will disappear instead of retract.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that throws the error? Also, maybe mock up a minimal case on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should transfer your props to components state so it can be cleared after delay. Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method to update state and clear it after delay you want. For transition, you need to set `key` attribute on child of `<Transition>` element (since you are animating only one child item key can be anything). Also, your `renderErrMsg()` method should always return a value so add `else return null` in your if statement.

Here is a working demo: http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/KVqgYg?editors=011

jsx:

```
const Transition = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

const Example = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: null
        };
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>submit</button>
                <Inner error={this.state.error} />
            </div>
        );
    },

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ error: 'error' });
    }

});

const Inner = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            error: null
        };
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: this.props.error
        };
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.error) {
            this.setState({ error: nextProps.error });
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                this.setState({ error: null });
            }, 3000);
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Transition
                    component="div"
                    transitionName="item"
                >
                    {this.renderErrMsg()}
                </Transition>
            </div>
        );
    },

    renderErrMsg() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            return (
                <div className="errMsg" key={1}>
                    {this.state.error}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


});

React.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

css:

```
.errMsg {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item-enter {
    top: -50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.item-enter-active {
    top: 50%;
}

.item-leave {
    top: 50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

.item-leave-active {
    top: -50%;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. Is this sequence correct: 1) submit clicked which triggers state change 2) since state changes, `componentWillUpdate` is triggered 3) `componentWillUpdate` triggers a timer which removes itself and the error state after 3 seconds. 4) as soon as the state changes, render will display the error message which will triggers its item-enter animation. 5) after 3 seconds, the error state is removed 6) render finds the error message is removed, thus removes the transition as well 7) item-leave and item-leave-active gets triggered

Comment: One more questions, I was reading the official doc. It says do not call `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate`. Also, `componentWillUpdate` does not return. So I wonder what `return this.setState({ error: null });` does in your code?

Comment: You are right, I missed that part of docs. You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead. Only difference is you now must explicitly update state when new props arrive. I updated my answer and code accordingly. As for return that's just my oversight. I'm used to having fat arrow functions always return value :)

Comment: There is no need to even maintain the state anymore. Because a prop is used instead. All you need is to update the prop instead of updating a state which mirrors the prop value

Comment: If you intend on updating prop by sending new value from parent then yes, no state is needed. Remember, it's not recommended to update prop from inside component. So in the end, it depends on how much of logic you want to have contained in your error render component and how much should be delegated (you could optionally expand `Inner` component to accept delay prop so you can control disappearing that way).